# Flutter FutureBuilder widget not responding to Future resolution when chaining Futures with await

Tags: flutter, dart, future, flutter-futurebuilder

I am using a flutter widget's `initState()` method to create two future ints; `delayed` which is a simple `Future.delay`, and `delayedAwaited`, which awaits on the `delayed` variable and doubles its value. The `build()` method includes two `FutureBuilder`s, one for each future. See example code below:

```
class FutureTest extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FutureTestState createState() => _FutureTestState();
}

class _FutureTestState extends State<FutureTest> {
  Future<int>? delayed;
  Future<int>? delayedAwaited;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initFutures();
  }

  void initFutures() async {
    delayed = Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () => 5);
    delayedAwaited = Future.value((await delayed)! * 2);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        FutureBuilder(
          future: delayed,
          builder: (context, snapshot) => Text('delayed: ${snapshot.data}'),
        ),
        FutureBuilder(
          future: delayedAwaited,
          builder: (context, snapshot) => Text('awaited: ${snapshot.data}'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the problem: The UI only updates for `delayed` and not `delayedAwaited` (it remains as null). The UI is updated to reflect the true value when manually hot-reloading, so the future is resolving correctly, but Flutter is just not triggering the `FutureBuilder` to rebuild. My expectation would be that the UI updates for `delayAwaited` as well.

See the behavior here: https://dartpad.dev/62b272db200ca39ed854be5a7183967d?null_safety=true

For some reason, changing `initFutures()` so it uses `Future.delayed` for both futures fixes the issue, as shown here: https://dartpad.dev/9b386a45428046b193800351a4ade5b1?null_safety=true

Is anyone able to explain **why** the given code works like this, and what is best practice for achieving what I am trying to do.

Comment: I'm guessing that delayedAwaited is never a future (since you await in front of it) so it goes right from null to the completed value.  Or something like that.  Get rid of await, and switch to a .then to set delayedAwaited.  Or I could be confused by your example. :)

Comment: As I understand it, async functions remove the need to use the .then pattern. The delayAwaited should be set to a future immediately, as I believe that is the behaviour of async functions. Is there a way to achieve this using only the async/await syntax? Source: https://youtu.be/SmTCmDMi4BY?t=90

Comment: Definitely still need for .then syntax sometimes.

Comment: adding `print(delayed); print(delayedAwaited);`at the first line of `build()` method will explain why that happens

Comment: @pskink you're exactly right, delayedAwaited shows as null. Is there a way to immediately assign it to a future that depends on another future's value, using the async/await semantics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way since you mentioned in the comments that you want to use async/await only:

```
 void initFutures() {
    delayed = fordelayed();
    delayedAwaited = fordelayedAwaited();
    
  }
  
  Future<int> fordelayed() async {
      return await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () => 5);
  }
  
  Future<int> fordelayedAwaited() async {
      int fromdelayed = await fordelayed();
      return fromdelayed * 2;
  }
```

Comment: I think this is the best solution. You can simplify further by removing `async` from `initFutures()`. I ended up going with the following syntax, for brevity: `delayedAwaited = Future(() async => (await delayed)! * 2);`. The pattern is to assign futures without using async/await directly, but use them within the callback functions (named as yours, or anonymous as mine).

Comment: I agree, the `async` from `initFutures()` is not needed. I will update it.